# How to load related data for a record already being tracked by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and my model classes were created automatically because I'm using Database First. I have the following two (simplified) classes:

```
public partial class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TeacherID { get; set; }
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

```
public partial class Teacher
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's say I create a new Student, thus:

```
MyDatabaseEntities db = new MyDatabaseEntities();
Student student = new Student()
{
    StudentName = "John Smith",
    TeacherID = 3
}
db.Student.Add(student);
db.SaveChanges();
```

As I say, this is all simplified. In reality the values for the fields are being posted from a form on a web page in which the value for the TeacherID is selected from a dropdown list.

Immediately after the record is created I want to populate a `StudentViewModel` which looks like this:

```
public class StudentViewModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
}
```

So right after my code to create the new student record I do this:

```
StudentViewModel model = new StudentViewModel()
{
    ID = student.ID,
    StudentName = student.StudentName,
    TeacherName = student.Teacher.TeacherName
}
```

This code throws a Null Reference Exception. I understand why, and I can get around it by doing this instead:

```
Student newStudent = db.Student
    .Where(s => s.ID == student.ID)
    .Include(s => s.Teacher)
    .FirstOrDefault();

StudentViewModel model = new StudentViewModel()
{
    ID = newStudent.ID,
    StudentName = newStudent.StudentName,
    TeacherName = newStudent.Teacher.TeacherName
};
```

My question is, given that the new student record is already being tracked by EF, is there any way to say "For this record, get the associated Teacher record", i.e. to essentially call the `.Include` function for a record already being tracked? Or is it always necessary to make a database call to get the record I just created and use `.Include`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#explicitly-loading

Comment: @GertArnold Want to put that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [explicit loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#explicitly-loading):

```cs
db.Entry(student).Reference(s => s.Teacher).Load();
```

But if you're a performance addict (like me) you may feel compelled to prevent loading a complete `Teacher` entity and query only the lean model from the database instead:

```cs
var model = db.Students.Where(s => s.ID == student.ID)
    .Select(s => new StudentViewModel
    {
        ID = s.ID,
        StudentName = s.StudentName,
        TeacherName = s.Teacher.TeacherName
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Anyway, you're always going to need a database call.