# Including categories entity inside products

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a service that creates a Product:

```
public async Task <ProductDTO> CreateProduct(ProductDTO product)
{

    Product myProduct = new Product()
    {
        //ProductId is Auto generated
         ProductName = product.ProductName,
         Price = product.Price,
         CategoryId = product.CategoryId,
         Category = product.Category
     };
        
    await _context.Products.AddAsync(myProduct);//Add Product to Products table
    await _context.Products.Include(i => i.Category).ToListAsync();
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();//Save all the changes

    product.ProductId = myProduct.ProductId;

    return product;         
}
```

In Postman when I run the application to post a new Product I get result like this:

```
{
    "productId": 1,
    "productName": "Milk",
    "price": 2,
    "categoryId": 1,
    "category": null
}
```

Although I used `Include(i => i.Category)` I still get null for the category

```
await _context.Products.Include(i => i.Category).ToListAsync();
```

Actually I can not use Include() function inside my ProductController class since my Controller only references my ProductService class. Can someone help me to fix this and Include Category entity in my CreateProduct service?
I am actually trying to fix it so that when I send the post request it looks like this:

```
{
    "productId": 1,
    "productName": "Milk",
    "price": 2.0,
    "categoryId": 1,
    "category": {
       "categoryId": 1,
       "categoryName": "Items"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to read the descriptions of the tags you're applying to a question.

Comment: `Include` only affects to reads, not inserts. Are you sure that `product.Category` is filled in the `ProductDTO` when you receive it? Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: Hmmm, hey, something that I noticed. You are correctly isolating DTO's from entities, but you try to assign `Category` in the `Product` entity which must be an entity with the `Category` from the `ProductDTO` that should be another DTO... there's something smelly.

Comment: You have `Task<ProductDTO> CreateProduct(ProductDTO product)` method which in the method you are returning the `product` as return, which is unnecessary, because it is class (reference type), whatever you do with it it's going to reflect the caller. So your method defenitino can be like `Task CreateProduct(ProductDTO product)`.

Comment: `_context.Products.Include(i => i.Category).ToListAsync();` is a needlessly expensive way to get only the one Category you want. Anyway, you should be able to `Load` the category, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64374161/861716.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers and Guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it by adding this line of code:

```
product.Category = myProduct.Category;
```

In this case Category is not null in postman